# Php mysql dynamic command string

Tags: php, mysql

I want to achieve to create command string based on parameters that are passed through `$_GET`.

So let's say I have 2 values. `ID` and `Group`

This is how I would hardcode to create command based on parameters that are passed

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'] && isset($_GET['Group']))
{
    $id = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['ID']);
    $g = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['Group']);

    $mySqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '$id' AND Group = '$g'";
}
else
{
    if(isset($_GET['ID'])
    {
        $id = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['ID']);

        $mySqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '$id'";
    }
    else
    {
        $g = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['ID']);

        $mySqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Group = '$g'";
    }
}
```

but problem is when there is about 10 possible parameters.

Idea I am having is doing it like I am doing it in my c# with coalesce:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = COALESCE(@passedID, ID) AND GROUP = COALESCE(@passedGROUP, GROUP)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passedID", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passedGroup", group);
```

Since coalesce returns first non-null object that is passed, even if I pass id as null it will then check if `ID = ID` and it is always true and that is how I do it in c#.

Is there any similar way doing it in php?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Since that's an SQL query, you want to know if MySQL has a [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function?

Comment: I saw it now and will use it but I have other problem and it is about binding parameters. I do not get it what is string used for in `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);`. What is `sss`?

Comment: @Pacijent As [documented quite clearly in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) the `sss` string (called the `types` parameter in the manual) is "A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables:".  It then goes on to list all the possible types you can specify. In other words, it's telling mysqli how to treat each parameter. `sss` indicates you are supplying 3 parameters and they are all strings. Whereas `ssi` would indicate the first two parameters are strings and the last one is an integer, for example.